# Setting button icon on SWT CCombo using CSS

Tags: java, css, swt, eclipse-rcp

According to https://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.rap.doc%2Fguide%2Freference%2Ftheming%2FCCombo.html the CCombo widget from SWT is themable, and the icon can be set.

I have the following CSS:

```
CCombo{
   background-color: rgb(00,255,00);  
}

CCombo Text {
   background-color: rgb(00,255,00);  
}

CCombo Button{
   background-color: rgb(00,255,00);
   background-image: url(ABSOLUTE PATH TO ICON);
}

CCombo Button-Icon{
   background-color: rgb(00,255,00);
   background-image: url(ABSOLUTE PATH TO ICON);
}

List[style~='SWT.DROP_DOWN']{
    background-color: rgb(00,255,00); 
}
```

And the background color is working fine. However I can't seem to get the icons working. I am using Linux to develop, however the application is deployed to windows7/10 so a solution for this platform would be sufficient for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible.

The down arrow in `CCombo` is created using the `SWT.ARROW | SWT.DOWN` style on `Button`.

This `setImage` method of `Button` specifically ignores any `setImage` call when the style is `SWT.ARROW` so the CSS styling will not work.

I am looking at the macOS SWT code, there may be differences on other platforms.

Comment: hmm if I look here: https://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?nav=%2F53_5_2 (widgets/Button)then it says that Button-ArrowIcon can be set. however even 'CCombo Button ArrowIcon' does not seem to work.

Comment: That link is for RAP - not plain SWT. If you are asking about RAP please specify that clearly in the question and tags.

Comment: ahh. sorry, That must have eluded  me. I am working on an RCP application.

Comment: Eclipse RCP is just plain SWT plus CSS styling provided by Eclipse plugins which just calls normal SWT methods on the controls. The RAP documentation is not relevant as that is completely different code.